# Why am I encountering an issue when trying to do calculations with documents from a firestore query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app that is able to determine the closest location to a given input point (in longitude and latitude). However, after creating a firestore query and using await getDocs with the query, when I try to use forEach() with the querySnapshot returned from getDocs, I get NaN when calculating the distance for each location document retrieved. I assume that this is due to the query not being fast enough at retrieving the documents before the code continues executing. The firebase documentation states that it would never return a undefined error, however.
[What firebase documentation states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BF9D.png)

I tried following the documentation, and this is what I wrote in my code:

```js
export default async function FindAllLocOfActAndCalcShortestDist(
  activity,
  eqPtLat,
  eqPtLong,
  setCalculatedLocDoc,
  setCalculatedLocDocFound
) {
  const locRef = collection(db, "locations");

  const q = query(locRef, where("activity", "==", activity)); // if we doing more than one activity at one location, can use array contains instead

  let shortestDist = 10000000000;
  let closestLocDoc;

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  querySnapshot.forEach((locationDoc) => {
    // console.log(locationDoc.id, " => ", locationDoc.data())
    let locDocData = locationDoc.data();
    let distance = HaversineFormula(
      eqPtLat,
      eqPtLong,
      locDocData.lat,
      locDocData.long
    );
    if (distance < shortestDist) {
      closestLocDoc = locationDoc;
      shortestDist = distance;
    }
  })

  console.log('reach combined function')

  setCalculatedLocDoc(closestLocDoc);
  setCalculatedLocDocFound(true);

}

export default function HaversineFormula(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) {
  const toRadian = angle => (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
  const distance = (a, b) => (Math.PI / 180) * (a - b);
  const RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_KM = 6371;

  const dLat = distance(lat2, lat1);
  const dLon = distance(long2, long1);

  lat1 = toRadian(lat1);
  lat2 = toRadian(lat2);

  // Haversine Formula
  const a =
    Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
    Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2), 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
  const c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));

  let finalDistance = RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_KM * c;

  console.log(finalDistance);

  return finalDistance;
}

// part of my code that invokes this function, along with other relevant functions

  // Method called when user press find location, for location algorithm
  const findLocations = () => {
    setSearchedLocations(true);
    CalcEqPtAndGetArrOfFriendsPref(
      profile,
      chosen_friends,
      friendList,
      setEqPtLat,
      setEqPtLong
    )
      .then((arrOfPref) => DetermineActType(arrOfPref))
      .then((activity) => FindAllLocOfActAndCalcShortestDist(activity, eqPtLat, eqPtLong, setCalculatedLocDoc, setCalculatedLocDocData, setCalculatedLocDocFound))
      .catch((e) => {console.log(e)}); 
    handleOpenOutingPopup();
  };

// other relevant functions
export default async function CalcEqPtAndGetArrOfFriendsPref(profile, chosen_friends, friendList, setEqPtLat, setEqPtLong) {
  let prefArr = [profile.pref];
  let coordsArr = [[profile.lat, profile.long]]
  const arrOfFriendIDsWithZero = chosen_friends.map((friendBool, ind) => {
    if (friendBool) {
      return friendList[ind].friend_id;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });

  const arrOfFriendIDs = arrOfFriendIDsWithZero.filter(n=>n!==0);

  console.log(arrOfFriendIDs);

  const usersRef = collection(db, "users");

  const q = query(usersRef, where("user_id", "in", arrOfFriendIDs));

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  querySnapshot.forEach((userDoc) => {
    const profData = userDoc.data();
    const friendPref = profData.pref;
    const friendCoords = [profData.lat, profData.long];
    prefArr.push(friendPref);
    coordsArr.push(friendCoords);
  })

  DetermineEqPt(coordsArr, setEqPtLat, setEqPtLong);
  return prefArr;
}

export default async function DetermineActType(arrOfArrOfBool) {
    let arrOfCount = new Array(arrOfArrOfBool[0]).fill(0);
    arrOfArrOfBool.map((arrOfBool, ind1) => {
        arrOfBool.map((bool, ind2) => {
            if (bool) {
                arrOfCount[ind2] += 1
            }
        })
    })
    let max_value = 0;
    let max_index = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrOfCount.length; i++) {
        if (arrOfCount[i] > max_value) {
            max_value = arrOfCount[i];
            max_index = i
        }
    }
    console.log("reach act type determined")
    console.log(max_index);
    return max_index;
}

export default function DetermineEqPt(arrOfCoords, setEqPtLat, setEqPtLong) {
    let totalLat = 0;
    let totalLong = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arrOfCoords.length; i++) {
        totalLat += arrOfCoords[i][0];
        totalLong += arrOfCoords[i][1];
    }

    let centroid_lat = totalLat / arrOfCoords.length;
    let centroid_long = totalLong / arrOfCoords.length

    console.log(centroid_lat);
    console.log(centroid_long);

    setEqPtLat(centroid_lat);
    setEqPtLong(centroid_long);
}
```

I thought that the execution would not return NaN for my Haversine function, but it does. I assume it is due to an undefined document retrieval from firebase? But it would contradict the firebase documentation.

[Fields for the location documents; no other subcollections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf4ur.png)

Comment: We can't really debug this for you because we can't see the contents of the database, and we can't see what `HaversineFormula` does. Without these, we don't know what the calculations would be.  Please edit the question to show the [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code that doesn't work the way you expect, and include enough information that anyone can use the reproduce the problem.

Comment: I apologise about the lack of information! will update the post to contain more information about this
if I may clarify, what information do you need about the contents of the database I am working with?

Comment: Some simple debugging would probably help you find the issue. Even some simple logging like `console.log('lat1', typeof lat1, lat1)`, etc

Comment: The functions are linked to a button click in my react app, when the button is clicked for the first time, I receive a NaN error on the first click, but on the second click, the code runs fine and I am able to get an answer from the code that I have written. It just seems like it doesn't run properly on the first run, but after some time has passed, the second run is able to determine the correct answer for me. Is there something that I have missed that anyone would be able to point out to me?? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What you just said should be part of your question that describes the behavior of the system, and you should also include the code that invokes the function, since that could also be part of the problem.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the behavior your describe.

Comment: I added the function that invokes this particular function from my code, as well as other functions that may cause issues. I believe that the querySnapshot forEach method should work, as I used it in another function (CalcEqPtAndGetArrOfFriendsPref) and that function manages to return the correct answer, but am unsure as to why the other calls to the Haversine function does not work as intended (returning a number instead of NaN) on the first invocation of the function when the button is pressed. Thanks for taking the time to assist me with my code, really appreciate it!